# how could i improve my loop in Python so that it can also take another sequence and put it in the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, bioinformatics

I am dealing with sequences in fasta file. Usually when the line starts with
this indicates the name of the sequence. And from the next line is the actual sequence.

I am trying to insert my sequences in a dictionary. So that the name is key and the actual sequence is value.
For example:

```
First line: >Ebola 23212
Second line: TAATCGTACTAC--ATCC
Third line: TAATATAGGCGT-A--
Fourth line: >Corona E0232.1
Fifth line: TATTTCGATC----AACT
```

And so on.

Here is what I have come up with so far

```
import sys

name= '/Users/Tom/OneDrive/Desktop/projekt/sequences.fasta'

from collections import defaultdict

f = open(name)

seq=defaultdict(str)

for line in f:

    if line.startswith('>'):

        name = line[1:-1]

        continue 

    seq[name]+=line.strip()
```

but this goes perfect if I only have one sequence in the file but with multiple sequences (and obviously multiple names) it fails. When I print name it gives me only the first sequence name.

any suggestions?

Comment: If you print name but what if you print seq ?

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel, use Biopython to read/write common bioinformatics formatted files: https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO

Comment: Thanks for your input but im trying to learn coding :)

Answer (score 0):

> Use Biopython

Biopython will help you achieve exactly what you are looking for.

> or Code it

If you prefer to code it you could implement this sort of pipeline:

```
def filter_nuc(letter):
    #extract the sequences by filtering to keep Nucleotides and ">" only
    nuc = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C', '>']
    return True if letter in nuc else False


# CHANGE__ the import directory is necessary to import a FASTA file
file_import_directory = "sample dataset.txt"

# import the FASTA file and read through
seq_orig = open(file_import_directory, "r")
seq = seq_orig.read()
seq_id = seq # for ID extraction
assert ">" in seq, "should be a valid FASTA file" # assert the imported file is a FASTA file

# extract the sequences as 'seq'
filtered_seq = filter(filter_nuc, seq)
new_seq = tuple(filtered_seq)
seq = ' '.join(new_seq)
seq = seq.replace(" ", "")
seq = seq.split('>')

#exclude repeated sequences
seq = [i for i in seq if seq.count(i) ==1]


def comparison(inp):
    #sort the list into a dictionary for easier comparison between sequences
    dict = {}
    n = 0
    i = len(inp)
    while n < i:
        dict[inp[n]] = []
        for letter in inp[n]:
            dict[inp[n]].append(letter)
        n += 1
    print(dict)
```

For example, for this input sequence:

```
>Rosalind_52
TCATC
>Rosalind_44
TTCAT
>Rosalind_68
TCATC
>Rosalind_28
TGAAA
>Rosalind_95
GAGGA
>Rosalind_66
TTTCA
>Rosalind_33
ATCAA
>Rosalind_21
TTGAT
>Rosalind_18
TTTCC
```

The expected output is:

```
{'TTCAT': ['T', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'T'], 'TGAAA': ['T', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'GAGGA': ['G', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'A'], 'TTTCA': ['T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'A'], 'ATCAA': ['A', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'A'], 'TTGAT': ['T', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'T'], 'TTTCC': ['T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C']}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the output you expect. I would still recommend using Biopython for reading and writing common files like fasta but if you really want to code it this should do the trick

```py
filename = '/path/to/sequences.fasta'
def create_sequence_dict(text: str) -> dict[str, str]:
    text = text.split('\n')
    name = text.pop(0)
    return {name: ''.join(iter(text))}


with open(filename, mode='r') as file:
    text = file.read()
d = {}

for s in sequence.split('>'):
    if s:
        d.update(create_sequence_dict(s) )
```

## Output

```py
{'Ebola 23212': 'STAATCGTACTAC--ATCCTAATATAGGCGT-A--',
 'Corona E0232.1': 'TATTTCGATC----AACT'}
```